# Capture DNS leakage

Tags: dns

I am trying to log DNS "leaks", in other words the DNS servers used by visitors to my web site.

How does one figure out which DNS server a web request came from to my server (i.e. the getting DNS leaks). This website [dnsleaktest.com](http://dnsleaktest.com) does it, it knows which DNS server I am coming from? How? It should only be able to know some stats about my browser, and maybe the HTTP referer. How does it know my DNS server?

What is being exploited, used? Or what is the traffic flow from my browser to this server, and where in that flow is dnsleaktest able to get this information?

Comment: I Don't think that's possible, perhaps they are the DNS server for themselves and simply do an IP match (they have probably multiple IP's that match the one requested)?

Comment: For some reason the URL did not show up in the original post. The site http://www.dnsleaktest.com/ does it. How do they do it?

Comment: @boruch, which IP are you referring to? How would they know the IP of my DNS server?

Comment: that is absolutely impossible, by design.  why do you use the term "leaks"?  What do you think is "leaking"?  dnsleaktest.com is about VPNs, and _only_ about VPNs, not about ordinary web servers and clients!

Comment: @greg-a-woods dnsleaktest.com was able to tell what my DNS server was. If it is impossible by design, how did it do it?  I am _not on any VPN_.  Did you try the website? Was it able to tell what your DNS service was?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not that easy.

What dnsleaks *probably* does - they have their own authoritative DNS server, javascript on their websites queries various randomly-generated subdomains of their domain, and on their DNS server they monitor where requests to those randomly-generated subdomains come from.

To do it, you need some domain hosted on **your own DNS servers** (not servers provided by your registrar or a hosting provider). You need to monitor queries to this server - can be done if you parse your DNS server logs or have your own DNS server software, or if your DNS server provides some API hooks to see the incoming requests. Then you write a script for your sites which queries various subdomains, and tells server-side script on your website which subdomain requests it should monitor. The server-side script in turn talks to the DNS server.

All the above is an unverified guess. I see no other way to do it.

Comment: thank you @Sandman4 for getting me closer to understanding this! Some questions -- when you say they query "randomly generated subdomains", is not true that DNS information for those domains has to be replicated on various DNS servers around the Internet, and they cannot control the exact server which resolves that domain or sub-domain? If so, how do they guarantee that my DNS request will reach them from my DNS server?

Comment: If you own a domain named dnsleaktest.com, queries to `laiuwerhflkjsfn.dnsleaktest.com` will be sent to one of __dnsleaktest.com__ DNS servers. Afterwards, other DNS servers may _cache_ the result, and thus subsequent queries may not reach dnsleaktest.com servers, that's why I assume they query new unique subdomains for each test.

Comment: Brilliant! All the pieces seem to fit, and I understand how they are probably doing this. Thanks!